# How can I selectively turn on or off specific categories of Code Analysis build warnings in VS2008?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, ide

Where is the HMI/Dialog/UI to pick and choose which types of build warnings that I'd like to be notified ?

e.g.

```
Warning 77  CA1725 : Microsoft.Naming : In member 'x', change parameter name 'a' to 'b' in order to match the identifier as it has been declared in 'd'.    <filename>
```

isn't as important as

```
Warning 75  CA2200 : Microsoft.Usage : 'a' rethrows a caught exception and specifies it explicitly as an argument. Use 'throw' without an argument instead, in order to preserve the stack location where the exception was initially raised.   <filename>
```

I've just inherited a ton of code.. and there is too much noise. I see a Suppress Messages(s) on a right click on the build warning... but I'm afraid I'd not be able to turn it back on :)

This seems to be more painful than necessary... Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it depends on the project type, but look in the project properties page under the "Build" tab if there is one. For example, in a C# project it's in the project properties, "Build", "Suppress warnings".

EDIT: This textbox is where you'd normally put in the warning numbers, e.g. 2200 and 1725. However, these are the options which are fed to the *compiler*. If this is an FxCop rule, I don't think it's going to help you.

You can [suppress FxCop messages in specific places using attributes](http://www.adrianbanks.co.uk/?p=30), or go to the project page and the "Code Analysis" tab for project-wide settings.

Comment: There's a nice blank textbox named 'Suppress Warnings:' but it's a lead nonetheless

Comment: Project Properties > Code Analysis is what I was looking for.. you're right CA error codes were not working for me in the Suppress Warnings textbox coz they are meant for compiler warnings with prefix CS I think. (Didn't know CA stood for code analysis.. until now.) Accepted.